# Cómo ocultar la url de un Iframe en React?

Tags: reactjs, url, iframe

Gracias de antemano

Estoy desarrollando un componente React en el cual coloco un Iframe para insertar una videoconferencia de Jitsi. Pero me solicitan que la URL de está reunión este oculta.

Este es el paquete que utilizo para el Iframe:

```
import Iframe from 'react-iframe';
```

El código del Iframe es el siguiente:

```
<Iframe url={meet.url}
    allow="camera; microphone; fullscreen; display-capture; autoplay"
    className={classes.meetIframe}
/>
```

Al inspeccionar en la consola la URL es visible. Cómo podría ocultarla?

Comment: Aqui tienes una posible solucion, solo adaptala a los iframes https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/345101/es-posible-ocultar-el-link-que-muestra-el-navegador-al-hacer-mouseover-en-un-enl

Comment: @HernánGarcia. Ese método no me permite asignar la url al Iframe